# Why does typescript fail to keep the right type info in array methods like map or find

Tags: typescript

In this example in the `if` scope the `p` property gets the type of an object but inside of the arrow function it is an object or `undefined`

```
const o: { p?: { sp?: string } } = { p: {} }
if (o.p) {
  const b = ['a'].map(x => {
    if (o.p.sp) {
      return x
    }
  })
}
```

I get a Object that is possibly '`undefined`' at the inner `if`

Why does this happen? How to fix it or is typescript just broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a limitation in the control flow analysis in TypeScript with the `strictNullChecks` option. There is no error without that option.

Assume the following simplified example:

```
const o: { p?: { sp?: string } } = { p: {} }
if (o.p) {
  if (o.p.sp) {
    // foo
  }
}
```

Here, the TypeScript compiler can easily infer that neither `o.p` nor `o` have changed since executing `if (o.p)`. As a result, it works without any error. But the problem arises as soon as you introduce more functionality like function calls which potentially could have side effects on `o`.

See [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for details. One example from the comments that might help to understand the issue is this code:

> ```
> if (token === SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword) {
>     nextToken();
>     if (token === SyntaxKind.DefaultKeyword) {
>         // We have "export default"
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

On first glance it does not make sense to nest the `if` clauses like that and TypeScript will warn you about it. However, `nextToken()` might actually change `token` and the code thus could make sense. But it is very hard for the compiler to actually understand and interpret situations like this correctly.

You could avoid the error message in your code by replacing `o.p.sp` with `o.p!.sp` or `o.p && o.p.sp`.